# Change div's html and show it while function is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I have a table with a `select` form element in each row. I want to change all selected values clicking a button, so that all `select` elements have the same selected value. I achieved it with this function (calling it when clicking the button):

```
function setStatus(s) {
    $('select').val(s).change();
}
```

This works well with a low number of rows. But when I have ~1000 rows it takes about 10 seconds to change all selects, and meanwhile the browser looks crashed.

I thought that at least I should display a spinner inside a div when a user clicks the button, and remove it when all selects have been changed. I did the following:

```
function setStatus(s) {
    $('#somediv').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    $('select').val(s).change();
    $('#somediv').html('');
}
```

But the result for the user is the exact same as before: the content of the div is not replaced (and/or shown) before the slow `.change()` function execution begins. I also tried to put each line in a separate function, with no success.

Comment: Just wondering...how/why are 1000 select elements being accessed at the same time?

Comment: Each row corresponds to a subject enrolled in some activity. At the end, the admin has to establish who participated, who did not, and some other possible statuses. around 95% of people participates, so it is convenient to have a button to set all statues at once and then change the 'other ones'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this issue could be swapping out `.html()` for `.fadeIn()`. This way rather than change an empty `<div>` to an icon you can fade it in and run the change function on completion.

I.e you could have `<div id="somediv"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i></div>`

CSS:

`#somediv { display: none; }`

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#somediv").fadeIn(300, function() {
      alert("hello");
    });
  });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2cua5t6o/